# How to find what causes a strange behaviour on bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have an issue with a dropdown that I've created by copying Bootstrap's example, but had to change buttons with links.
Here is the [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2aebs0u9/)
This code:

```
<a class="nav-link nav-link " href="#">aaa</a>
<a class="nav-link  nav-link dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" 
   data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></a>
```

shows a text (aaa) and a dropdown arrow that opens the menu. The problem is that on the jfiddle I created to test my issue, everything is OK. The version I have on my code (maybe with a different bootstrap minor version and other stuff) shows the small triangle in the wrong place. It is on the top of its space instead of being centered like on jfiddle.
How do I investigate what is the issue? I tried checking with Firefox's developer tool what was wrong but I didn't mange to find the culprit.

There is no example around the web using  links instead of , I thought that was a possible reason, but it does not explain why the jsfiddle example works.

Edit: [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8uq1oxwh/) is a more complete code. It runs correctly on jsfiddle. It doesn't run correctly when I run standalone. Both on chrome.

Edit 2: I have problems with jfiddle: here is the complete code: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/3bk6L7ct/1/)

Comment: Is your code the same as what you have in the jsfiddle?

Comment: The code is the same but there are more stuff before and after it.

Comment: @DavidLiang I've added the full source. Test it outside jsfiddle to see the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem.
Apparently the issue is that the html code doesn't start with

```
<!doctype html>
```

I don't know why/how it might screw up the caret.

@Aditya Thakur 's answer is also correct: the `<a></a>` of the caret shouldn't be empty **if I don't specify the doctype**. +1 for his answer but I suppose this should be the correct one.

[Always define a doctype on any html documents](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Choosing_the_right_doctype_for_your_HTML_documents)

Answer (score 1):

The anchor tag `<a class="dropdown-toggle">` that is supposed to have this caret is empty, causing the caret to get pushed upwards. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/hThNl.jpg

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/" id="navbarDropdownCategories" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></a>
```

If you add something inside the anchor tags, the carets placement gets fixed. The reason it was not reproducible in jsfiddle was because it wasn't empty in jsfiddle. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQYKo.jpg

```
 <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/" id="navbarDropdownCategories" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">aaa</a>
```

And in your css to fine tune the caret

```
 .dropdown-toggle::after {
        vertical-align: middle !important;
    }
```

Here's the js fiddle for the same: https://jsfiddle.net/yhbo4w6L/

Comment: It still doesn't work. Please have a look at my updated question. You have to run the code outside jsfiddle though.

Comment: @maugch, i was able to fix the issue using the same css rule in my local machine, i am not sure, why are you having this issue, let me show you the screenshot https://imgur.com/a/P4syoLP

Comment: here is mine https://imgur.com/a/Mjzsymv. with or without your rule. Please have a look at my second edit and try to run it outside jsfiddle.

Comment: @maugch Thanks for providing the actual code, i have found the issue.

Comment: I've found the issue, see my answer. Your solution seems not to work when I change the code by hand as you said. I wonder where the issue really is. Note that I expect my solution to be better only because I believe Bootstrap's team wouldn't have done the mistake you try to correct with !important.

Comment: @maugch **" I wonder where the issue really is"**, ---> Empty **<a></a>** tag?

Comment: Sure, that could be, but on chrome it didn't work when I just added something inside the <a> tag. Interestingly now that I try with Firefox on Linux, it does indeed. I might add that on firefox (linux?) both adding doctype or adding something inside <a> does work.